# How to read Div inner contents at ajax?

Tags: html, sql, ajax, json

I'm trying to update the sql db by a List of variables sent from the Html page.
Some of the Data are correctly sent, while others are not. I put the list in a div which is divided to two parts : "h1" and another "Div". The data at the header are all sent correctly, but the body itself which is at the second div isn't sent at all. 
This is the Div which the data is put at:

```
    $('#Classes').append('<div> <h1 class = "flip" wpID="' + subjects[i].Wkp_ID + '" lessonID="' + subjects[i].Ttb_lessonID + '" Date="' + Datecoming + '">' + subjects[i].sbj_Name + " Class:" + subjects[i].Ttb_Class + '</h1><div id ="NewBody" class="panel" contenteditable>' + subjects[i].Wkp_Body + '</div> </div>');
```

And that's how I read them at the ajax part:

```
    var WeekPlan = [];
    $('#Classes div').each(function (index) {
        var header = $(this).children('h1');
        var WeekBody = $(this).children('div').val();
        var wpID = header.attr('wpID');
        var lessonID = header.attr('lessonID');
        var Wkp_Date = header.attr('Date');

        WeekPlan[index] = { "Wkp_ID": wpID, "Wkp_Date": Wkp_Date, "Wkp_Body": WeekBody, "Wkp_lesson": lessonID }; 
        });
```

The Wkp_ID, Wkp_Date, Wkp_Lesson are right, but the Wkp_Body just returns an empty string. 
So do you know why is this happening and how can I truly read the body ? Most probably the problem is with this line:

```
    var WeekBody = $(this).children('div').val();
```

But how can I access it correctly ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to read the content of your div ? If so you should use .text() or .html() instead of .val().

Comment: Yes I'm trying to read the content of the div, but it's not reading anything. I tried  var WeekBody = $(this).children('div').html(); &  var WeekBody = $(this).children('div').text(); but both returns an empty string too. .. Should I change the statement itself ?

Comment: if this is $('#Classes div') there doesn't seem to be a need to add children. You could use directly $(this).text(). But I'm not sure I understood the whole problem. If you're trying to understand what's in an element, my advice is to type in the Chrome console something like this : $('#Classes') and after that to refine your query if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me in case anyone needs it:

Creating the div:

```
                 $('#Classes').append('<div class="BigDiv"> <h1 class = "flip" wpID="'+ subjects[i].Wkp_ID + '" lessonID="' + subjects[i].Ttb_lessonID + '" Date="' + Datecoming + '">' + subjects[i].sbj_Name + " class:" + subjects[i].Cls_Name + '</h1><div class="panel" contenteditable>' + subjects[i].Wkp_Body + '</div> </div>');
```